# Upload of large files with ckeditor and imagick takes very long time

Tags: ckeditor, upload, imagick

I have a custom text field where the user is allowed to link text with uploaded files via ckeditor (respectively kcfinder). Currently the upload of files does take a very long time. It's not a network issue because the actual request is sent after a few seconds. There seems to be an additional step afterwards, which delays the response for minutes (e.g. for a file with size of 4.7MB):

[image: upload request details]

If I upload the file via a standard upload input (non ckeditor) the request is finished in seconds.

Here are some details about the request:

[image]

*Using CiviCRM 4.7.23 with Drupal 7.56 on CentOS with Plesk, Apache and FastCGI.*

I do not have this issue on my local dev machine, only on this server.

What could cause this delay? Are there any relevant CiviCRM or server settings?

**UPDATE:** After adding some error log calls including the current timestamp I could face down the function, which is causing the delay. It is `$img = image::factory($this->imageDriver, $file['tmp_name']);` where `$this->imageDriver` has the value `imagick`. It seems that the creation of the *imagick* object is taking way to long (the following image tasks are done quickly). Any idea what could cause this?

After disabling `imagick` and using `gd` instead the upload is finished in seconds.

Comment: Whats the contents of the headers tab?

Comment: @DavidHayes Check my updated question.